# Inconsistent results from DateTime.UtcNow

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

While troubleshooting a problem in code I've been contracted to build I've run across what appear to be inconsistent results from `DateTime.UtcNow`. The time appears to be fluctuating between 1/19/2017 7:3x and 1/20/2017 3:2x at the time I am writing this.

I've created an [example on IdeOne](http://ideone.com/jHg0Y2) using the following code; click 'edit', then 'ideone it!' - it may take several runs before the behavior is displayed.

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow);
    }
}
```

Screencap:

[image: screenshot]

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Comment: Can you define inconsistent results please?

Comment: @ChrisWatts edits above

Comment: Have you seen this behavior anywhere else but at IdeOne? They probably have several machines compiling and running code which could be configured differently.

Comment: @Chrille - yes; the application I am building gave an incorrect validation failure response, essentially claiming the UTC date was not currently 2017/01/19 on my client's server, not IdeOnes.

Comment: @Chrille No "probably" about it, that's exactly what's happening. I was checking before answering. :)

Comment: So this is a good reason to write your code using "mock the clock" or "virtual clock" patterns.  See Noda Time's `IClock`/`SystemClock`/`FakeClock` stuff, or just google for other implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ideone uses multiple servers, and your program does not always run on the same one. One of the servers simply has its system clock set incorrectly.

Your own server can equally have its system clock set incorrectly, causing the same problems when requesting the time.

Comment: Good thought - wonder if someone is toying with settings while I'm running live tests...

Comment: I don't think this problem implies that someone's toying with settings, but rather that different servers are responding to your request.

Comment: By writing out the value of the system's timer with `Console.WriteLine(System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp());` you can see that it is also giving very different values implying that you're dealing with different systems that have been running for different amounts of time.